# How to prevent Sequelize from inserting NULL for primary keys with Postgres

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I have created a table in postgresql 9

```
create table stillbirth(id serial primary key, state varchar(100), count int not null, year int not null);
```

trying to write a sample on node.js with sequelize 1.4.1 version.

mapped the above table as

```
var StillBirth = sequelize.define('stillbirth',
{ id: {type: Sequelize.INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true},
state: Sequelize.STRING,
year: Sequelize.INTEGER,
count: Sequelize.INTEGER
}, {timestamps: false, freezeTableName: true});
```

now when i try to create a new instance of Stillbirth and save it, i get errors.

/** new instance create code **/

```
StillBirth
   .build({state: objs[j].state, year: objs[j].year, count: objs[j].count})
   .save()
   .error(function(row){
         console.log('could not save the row ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        })
   .success(function(row){
       console.log('successfully saved ' + JSON.stringify(row));
   })
```

error i get

*Executing: INSERT INTO "stillbirth" ("state","year","count","id") VALUES ('Andhra Pradesh',2004,11,NULL) RETURNING *;
could not save the row {"length":110,"name":"error","severity":"ERROR","code":"23502","file":"execMain.c","line":"1359","routine":"ExecConstraints"}*

If you look at the sql that its generating, it puts null for the primary key which should ideally be generated by the db.

Can someone help me as to what am i missing here ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You have to instantiate Sequelize with a special flag called `omitNull`:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pw', {
  omitNull: true
})
```

This will `disable inserting undefined values as NULL`. http://sequelizejs.com/#usage-options

You might need to update to v1.5.x or 1.6.0-betaX

Comment: Thanks that worked with the 1.5.x version, surprisingly the NPM registry https://npmjs.org/package/sequelize doesnt mention anything about the 1.5.0 version.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that when you try to perform an update like this user.save({address:null}); it doesn't change the address in the DB. Is there any way to perform an update an set an attribute to null?

Comment: Given the rate their docs mutate, that link is long dead. Sure would like to know what's going on with this because it just started happening to me and I want to know why.

Comment: @lao, this is a global setting. You can always pass a local override: `user.save({address:null}, {omitNull: false})`

Comment: Bullseye! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

To expand on the answer from `sdepold`, as he recommended, you can `omitNull` to prevent sequelize from adding `null` values to the generated SQL. In general, this is good, and it also allows you to perform partial updates.

```js
var sequelize = new Sequelize('db', 'user', 'pw', {
  omitNull: true
})
```

There is one caveat, though. How do you set a column to `null` if that's legitimately what you want to do?? The answer is that you can pass `omitNull` as part of your save.

```js
user.address = null;
user.save({omitNull: false});
```

OR

```js
user.update({address: null}, {omitNull: false});
```

Answer (score 2):

It is also possible to define which attributes can be set via the create method. Using that would for example allow you to restrict the User model to set only a username and an address but not an admin flag:

```
User.create({ username: 'barfooz', isAdmin: true }, { fields: [ 'username' ] }).then(user => {
  // let's assume the default of isAdmin is false:
  console.log(user.get({
    plain: true
  })) // => { username: 'barfooz', isAdmin: false }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a workaround this without using omitNull.

Just do this:

```
StillBirth
   .build({state: objs[j].state, year: objs[j].year, count: objs[j].count})
   .save(['state','year','count'])
   .error(function(row){
         console.log('could not save the row ' + JSON.stringify(row));
        })
   .success(function(row){
       console.log('successfully saved ' + JSON.stringify(row));
   })
```

By sending an array of properties as parameter for save method you force sequelize to insert only the properties of that array omiting the id, leaving to the DB to auto create the id for you. =)